# removing the input text in the text field that matches the removed tab

Tags: javascript, html

In this example I made, since it uses `keyup` event, each input text (separated by comma) entered is converted into a tab. I want the input text to be deleted from the text field according to the tab I remove; for example, I enter "Item 1" but I suddenly change my mind and decide to remove the "Item 1" tab, the input text in the text field that has a string that matches the `textContent` of the removed tab should be automatically deleted from the text field.

```js
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

query('#textfield').addEventListener('keyup', addTag);

function addTag(e) {
  var evt = e.target;

  if(evt.value) {
    var items = evt.value.split(',');

    if(items.length <= 10) {
      evt.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = null;

      for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if(items[i].length > 0) {
          var label = document.createElement('label'),
              span = document.createElement('span');
          
          label.className = 'tag';
          label.textContent = items[i];

          span.className = 'remove';
          span.title = 'Remove';
          span.textContent = 'x';

          label.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', span);

          evt.nextElementSibling.appendChild(label);

          span.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var currentElement = this;

            currentElement.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(currentElement.parentNode);
          })
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    evt.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = null;
  }
}
```

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

  background: orange;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
}

input[name] {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
  font: 1rem 'Arial', sans-serif;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #272727;
  color: orange;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 0 orange;
}

input[name]::placeholder {
  font: 0.9rem 'Arial', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.tags {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #dfdfdf;
  border-radius: 0 0 1rem 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position: relative;
}

.tags > label {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #272727;
  color: orange;
  font: 1.1rem 'Arial', sans-serif;
  padding: 0.4rem 0.6rem;
  border-radius: .2rem;
  margin: 5px;
}

.tags > label > span {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2px;
  color: #ff4d4d;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section id="tags-input">
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" name="items" id="textfield" placeholder="Enter any item, separated by comma(','). Maximum of 10" autofocus>
    <div class="tags"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How can I make that feature possible?

Comment: An easier, and cleaner solution would give each item their own input. You can dynamically add and remove these HTML elements when an item is deleted based on their value, instead of parsing the text in a single input to find where text matches a tab to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the 'x' button listener with this one:

```
span.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var text_field = document.getElementById("textfield");
    var evt = this.parentNode;
    var tags = text_field.value;
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this); // remove the 'x' span so you can get the pure tag text with .innerHTML
    var evname = evt.innerHTML;
    var tags_array = tags.split(",");
    var tag_position = tags_array.indexOf(evname);
    if(tag_position > -1)
        tags_array.splice(tag_position,1);
    text_field.value = tags_array.join(',');
    evt.parentNode.removeChild(evt);
})
```

// Coding this complexity in pure javascript when there is jQuery is ... like eating soup with a fork. You will get the job done, but it is dammn hard!

Comment: I understand. But I think I like the complexity of vanilla JS more than the less-code-and-easy feature of jQuery. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, really appreciated it :)